# spl-dkms fails to compile for 4.13.0-32 on xenial

Tags: 16.04, zfs, dkms

I'm running xenial with a `zfs` root (and `zfs-initramfs`).

While updating, apt installed a kernel upgrade to 4.13.0-32 via `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04`. `dkms` compilation of `spl` (from `spl-dkms-0.6.5.6-0ubuntu4`) failed with the following output:

```
Running the pre_build script:
checking for gawk... gawk
[...]
checking whether struct rw_semaphore member wait_lock is raw... yes
checking whether header linux/sched/rt.h exists... yes
checking whether vfs_getattr() wants... configure: error: unknown

Building module:
cleaning build area....(bad exit status: 2)
make KERNELRELEASE=4.13.0-26-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/spl-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/spl/0.6.5.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

Googling for that failed configure lead me to [this spl issue](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/spl/issues/618), which seems to say that 0.6.5.6 won't work for 4.13 kernels.

I've currently downgraded my kernel and set `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04` on hold so I can at least boot again. What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have specif reason to run 4.13 kernel, you could try earlier version (for example, 4.10), against which zfs and spl dkms compile just fine. You can download it from [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10/) and then:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure spl-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure zfs-dkms
```

Version 4.10 already works with [TCP BBR congestion control](https://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/increase-your-linux-server-internet-speed-with-tcp-bbr-congestion-control/) (if by aby chance you were looking fot his.)

Comment: The only reason is that I'd like my kernel to get upgrades. I guess I could switch to the non-hwe metapackage (I don't actually know why the hwe version is used on my system), but I'm a bit surprised that this conflict arises at all, since both the kernel and the spl package are from the official xenial repositories. So I'm a bit afraid it might just break again with another update.

Comment: If you don't have specif need for newer kernel (like some hardware not working), stick to the one provided by default repos.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing for now. Strangely enough, the package still fails to compile, but zfs works. This is annoying.